# how does 'fetch chromium' work? How to edit gclient config

Tags: chromium

I am trying to download the chromium code, I am doing it for the first time.
After many hours 'fetch chromium' failed due to OutOfMemory exception. Its here [on chromium issues](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=349576)

My question is: 
How do I configure my .gclient (where is this located) to ignore some git clones operations?
Where can I find the list of actions that gclient does to fetch the code? Is there some list of dependencies defined somewhere?
Can I restart 'fetch' operation skipping already downloaded ones?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding OOM error during fetch:

```
    This should be fixed now: https://codereview.chromium.org/202753003/
    Please make sure your checkout of depot_tools is up to date...
```

And regarding how fetch works, you can always check fetch script in **depot_tools/fetch.py**

.gclient is present in directory where you're checking out code (hidden file , ctrl+h ?)

To ignore syncing some projects you can select custom_deps like this, 
but strongly advised to not do this anyway..

```
 "custom_deps": {
  "src/third_party/WebKit": None,   
},
```

more from here:
[Advanced_Usage](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chromium-modularization#Advanced_Usage) 
[get_the_code](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code)

Comment: The actual problem is this. I was running a 64 bit OS with <4GB RAM. So the gcm_utils.py queries platform bit (32 or 64) and assumes you have enoughy memory, which is >4gb and uses -2g or -512m in fetching.

Answer (score 0):

On a 64 bit OS with <4GB RAM, the gcm_utils.py queries platform bit (32 or 64) and assumes you have enoughy memory, which is >4gb and uses -2g instead of -512m in fetching.

So if you have less memory on a 64bit, you might have to edit the utils file and change it to 512m or equivalent.